# Can't login due to losing power during an update

Tags: updates

Few days ago while Ubuntu 12.04 was doing a common system update, my laptop turned off in the middle of process due to bad AC power. Since then, I can only login but nothing else. A message about compiz appears, but mouse, keyboard, icons, Unity are not working.

The only thing I was able to do is a boot repair, as described in Ubuntu's site, but neither this helped. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you boot to **[recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode)** entry? If you can, it should show you a small menu.

In that menu:

- select Network to activate the network (internet),
- then select Drop    to root shell.

That will load a command prompt as root.

Then you can try:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get install -f
```

Usually that can help with broken packages.